# GtkTextView automatically resizing

Tags: c, gtk, gtktextview

I'm messing around with GTK and glade for the first time, and I've run across a really annoying issue. When I enter text into a TextView, the TextView automatically resizes larger, pushing other widgets away.

This is a really annoying behavior. I do not want my TextView changing size depending on the amount of text within it.

Does anyone know what I can do to prevent the TextView from resizing based on its content?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should put `GtkTextView` into `GtkScrolledWindow` with "`hscrollbar-policy`" and "`vscrollbar-policy`" properties set to "`automatic`".

Answer (score 1):

I may have asked a bit too soon.

The answer is, the TextView must go inside a scrolled window.

Hopefully someone else will run across this problem one day, and this solution will help them.

Answer (score 1):

Even inside `GtkScrolledWindow` with `GTK_POLICY_NONE GtkTextView` resizes itself while adding text. That's pretty nasty - impossible to have `GtkTextView` without scrollbars.